# Can the Auger effect cause a second electron to be just excited instead of ionised and emitted from the atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

From what I understand, the Auger effect is usually defined as when an electron deexcites but instead of releasing its change in binding energy as a photon, it transfers it as kinetic energy to another electron which, if greater than its binding energy, will cause this second electron to be emitted from the atom.

My question is why is this process defined with the second electron being emitted from the atom instead of just excited to a higher energy state sometimes.

My guess is maybe it has something to do with entropy and the fact that there are so many more possible states for the second electron final state if it is emitted that maybe only in this case will this process actually occur (instead of just emitting a photon as usual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why is this process defined with the second electron being emitted from the atom instead of just excited to a higher energy state sometimes.

The atom is a unit tied up quantum mechanically . To observe transformations of an atom, there must be an interaction that can be measured. An emitted photon can be measured. An emitted electron can also be measured. If the whole process happens within an atom, there is no measurable/observable effect. An electron just going to a higher energy level can emit a photon when de-exciting , but there is no measurable way to determine that it comes from a transfer from a different electron, the way there is for an ejected electron to be identified with a different energy level:

> [Upon ejection,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auger_effect) the kinetic energy of the Auger electron corresponds to the difference between the energy of the initial electronic transition into the vacancy and the ionization energy for the electron shell from which the Auger electron was ejected.

Comment: What if the excited second electron deexcites in multiple stages emitting several lower energy photons? That would be measurably different to just the first electron emitting a high energy photon.

Comment: It wouldnot fall in the definition of auger electron, which needs one transition. If there is a  QM probability for this to happen it would be a different reaction, imo

Comment: By one transition, do you mean ionisation only for the auger electron?

Comment: @AlexGower  yes, no photons emitted in the Auger electron case , if there are several transition there should be photons

Comment: Okay so in this case you’re saying my OP was trivial, Auger electrons are *defined* to be emitted even though other processes are indeed possible

Comment: You have it  "when an electron deexcites but instead of releasing its change in binding energy as a photon, it transfers it as kinetic energy to another electron"

Comment: But in my original post I thought that was ambiguous as the other electron could gain kinetic energy but still be bound

Comment: So, to be 100% sure, you’re saying that Auger means one electron has to be ionised?

Comment: My answer addresses this last , if it is bound it cannot be detected, it is the detection of a free electron with a characteristic energy that makes it an auger one.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first note that Auger process is due to Coulomb interaction between electrons, so it may be beneficial to think of it in terms of the Fermi golden rule:
$$
w_{i_1 i_2\rightarrow f_1 f_2}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|\langle i_1, i_2 | V|f_1, f_2\rangle|^2\delta(\epsilon_{i_1} + \epsilon_{i_2} - \epsilon_{f_1} - \epsilon_{f_2})
$$.
One needs to be careful when calculating the matrix element to account properly for the exchange term, but what interests us at the moment is the energy conservation, codified here in the delta-function. If the first electron changes its energy between two levels:
$\epsilon_{i_1}-\epsilon_{f_1} = E_n-E_m$ than the second electron must increase its energy by the same amount: $\epsilon_{f_2}-\epsilon_{i_2} = E_n-E_m$.

- If, e.g., we were discussing Auger recombination in a semiconductor crystal, then satisfying this condition would be rather easy, since there are many states available in the condiction band. In an atom with discrete levels this however could be tricky, so being ejected into the continuum of states is the only option.
- Another consideration is the pure size of the energy change. If we take hydrogen-like spectrum
  $$
  E_n=-\frac{E_1}{n^2}.
  $$
  then
  $$
  E_n - E_1 = E_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) > \frac{1}{n^2} \text{ for any } n>1.
  $$

Comment: What do you mean about finding an energy state with the correct energy being tricky for an atom with discrete levels?